# TreeSet in Java

Tags: java, set, treeset

I understand Java best practice suggests that while declaring a variable the generic set interface is used to declare on the left and the specific implementation on the right.

Thus if I have to declare the Set interfaces, the right way is,

```
Set<String> set = new TreeSet<>();
```

However with this declaration I'm not able to access the `set.last()` method.
However when I declare it this way,

```
TreeSet<String> set = new TreeSet<>();
```

I can access, `last()` and `first()`.
Can someone help me understand why?

Answer (score 5):

The`last()` and `first()` are specific methods belonging to `TreeSet` and not the generic interface `Set`. When you refer to the variable, it's looking at the source type and not the allocated type, therefore if you're storing a `TreeSet` as a `Set`, it may only be treated as a `Set`. This essentially *hides* the additional functionality.

As an example, every class in Java extends `Object`. Therefore this is a totally valid allocation:

`final Object mMyList = new ArrayList<String>();`

However, we'll never be able to use `ArrayList` style functionality when referring directly to `mMyList` without applying *type-casting*, since all Java can tell is that it's dealing with a generic `Object`; nothing more.

Comment: Only one that answers question the best +1

Answer (score 2):

You can use the SortedSet interface as your declaration (which has the `first()` and `last()` methods).

Answer (score 1):

The interface of `Set` does not provide `last()` and `first()` because it does not always make sense for a `Set`.

Java is a static typing language.  When compiler see you doing `set.last()`, as it is expecting `set` to be a `Set`.  It will not know whether `set` is a `TreeSet` that provides `last()`, or it is a `HashSet` that does not.  That's why it is complaining.

Hold on.  You do not need to declare it using the concrete class `TreeSet` here.  `TreeSet` bears a `SortedSet` interface which provides such methods.  In another word: because you need to work with a `Set` that is sorted (for which it make sense to provide `first()` and `last()`), the interface that you should work against should be `SortedSet` instead of `Set`

Hence what you should be doing is

```
SortedSet<String> set = new TreeSet<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the existing answers here, the reason is that `TreeSet` implements the interface `NavigableSet` which inherits from the interface `java.util.SortedSet` the methods comparator, **first**, **last** and spliterator.

Just the `Set`, on the other side, doesn't have `SortedSet` methods because it's not inherit from it.

[image]

Check it out from more [Java TreeSet examples](https://javatutorial.net/java-treeset-example).